# Propose java mail api please

Tags: java, api, email, unix

I'd like to open single-file unix mailbox using some free java library. I want to list messages, get their bodies and adresses plus get their attaches. What library should I use.

Thank you.

Comment: Start with JavaMail. Commons Email is better suited for sending mails. And voting to close this question as it will only solicit a discussion, without sufficient facts in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [JavaMail API in Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). Of course you can also use it stand-alone. Pretty much the default choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think JavaMail already does this.

If you're looking for additional functionality, the Apache James project has an [`MBoxMailRepository`](http://james.apache.org/server/3/apidocs/org/apache/james/mailrepository/file/MBoxMailRepository.html) class that builds in additional stuff.